# Compute double complex integral: $\int_{|\zeta|=2} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\zeta}{\zeta+\sin\theta} d\theta d\zeta$.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am trying to compute the following integral: $$\int_{|\zeta|=2} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\zeta}{\zeta+\sin\theta} d\theta d\zeta.$$
I know that if $\zeta \in \mathbb R$ with $|\zeta|>1$, then the inner integral would equal $\dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}$; however, I don't think this works for general $\zeta \in \mathbb C$. According to Mathematica, $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{(2e^{i \varphi})^2 - 1}}d\varphi = 4\pi^2 i.$$

On the other hand, if I rewrite $\zeta = 2 e^{i\varphi}$ and thus convert the integral to $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{2 e^{i\varphi}}{2 e^{i\varphi}+\sin\theta} d\theta d\varphi = 4\pi^2,$$
according to Mathematica. Is this correct, and how can I prove it?

Interestingly, if I change $|\zeta|=2$ to being any $\zeta\in\mathbb C$ with modulus greater than $1$, then the integral converges to some value relatively close to $4\pi^2$ (and for integers, it will be equal). I think that there's some clever trick that I'm clearly not seeing.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The you know about the principle of analytic continuation?

Comment: @Gary: Yes, I do. I forgot to include in the original post but if I use computer software to compute $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{(2e^{i \varphi})^2 - 1}}d\varphi$, the integral equals $4\pi^2 i$ - which isn't equal to $4\pi^2$

Comment: $$
{\rm d}\zeta  = \frac{{{\rm d}\zeta }}{{{\rm d}\varphi }}{\rm d}\varphi  = \frac{{{\rm d}(2{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\varphi } )}}{{{\rm d}\varphi }}{\rm d}\varphi  = 2{\rm ie}^{{\rm i}\varphi } {\rm d}\varphi 
$$

Comment: Ahhhh, of course. I see where I went wrong now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing the order of the integrals, we get $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{|\zeta|=2} \frac{\zeta}{\zeta+\sin(\theta)}d\zeta d\theta$$

As $\frac{\zeta}{\zeta+\sin(\theta)}=1-\frac{\sin\theta}{\zeta+\sin\theta}$ and by Cauchy's integral theorem, $$\int_{|\zeta|=2}(1-\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\zeta+\sin(\theta)})d\zeta=-\sin(\theta)\int_{|\zeta|=2}\frac{1}{\zeta+\sin(\theta)}d\zeta=-\sin(\theta)2\pi i$$

since $\sin(\theta)$ is always enclosed by $|\zeta|=2$ for all $\theta$.

Therefore the original integral is simply $-2\pi i\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(\theta)d\theta=0$.

Even if $|\zeta|=2$ is replaced by any $|\zeta|=r$ for $r>1$, the same argument and conclusion hold.

Actually it's $\rho(\zeta):=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\zeta+\sin\theta}d\theta = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}$ without the extra $\zeta$ on the top of the first integral. Note that the integral representation defines an analytic function over $\mathbb C\setminus [0, 1]$, in particular we know that $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}$ has analytic continuation over the plane except $[0, 1]$ (which should also be clear through the standard technique of branch cut), and the integral is essentailly the residue of the function $\zeta\rho(\zeta)$ around $\infty$, but i don't see an easy way to calculate the residue yet.